# Dynamically add meta description based on route in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular 5 to build a small brochure type website. Thus far, I have my routes set up, and the page title changes dynamically based on the activated route. I got this working using the instructions on this blog: https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events

I'm currently storing my routes and titles in app.module.ts as such:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { 
        path: '', 
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Home'
        }
      },
      { 
        path: 'about', 
        component: AboutComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'About'
        } 
      },
      { 
        path: 'products-and-services', 
        component: ProductsServicesComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Products & Services'
        }  
      },
      { 
        path: 'world-class-laundry', 
        component: LaundryComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'World Class Laundry'
        }  
      },
      { 
        path: 'contact', 
        component: ContactComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Contact'
        }  
      },
      { 
        path: '**', 
        component: NotFoundComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Page Not Found'
        }  
      }
    ])
  ],
```

I'd like to store my meta descriptions there as well, if adding them under `data:` would be easy enough.

I'm pulling in that title data with the following code, which is noted in the blog link above:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
      .map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
      })
      .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
      .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']);
      });
  }
```

So my question is, is there a way to dynamically set the meta description using the same method? If there is a way to combine the page title and meta description function, that would be ideal.

I have very limited Angular training, so this might be a nooby question. I'm more of a designer/css/html kind of guy.

Comment: since angular 4 there is already a build in service that does that import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  see here https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta

Comment: @elasticrash Yes, I looked into Meta. I'm more interested in how to implement Meta into what I already have.

Comment: Where is the  meta description ?

Comment: @Melchia If possible, I'd like to store my meta descriptions with the page titles is app.module.ts.

Comment: Can't you just add an attribute description in data & do the same thing you did in ngOnInit ?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

First create a SEOService or Something like below:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'; 
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable({
  provideIn: 'root' // Add this to ensure your SEO service will be app-wide available
})
export class SEOService {
  constructor(private title: Title, private meta: Meta) { }


  updateTitle(title: string) {
    this.title.setTitle(title);
  }

  updateOgUrl(url: string) {
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:url', content: url })
  }

  updateDescription(desc: string) {
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: desc })
  }
}
```

**After injecting the SEOService** in your component (app.component.ts preferably), set meta tags and title in OnInit method

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.pipe(
       filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
       map(() => this.activatedRoute),
       map((route) => {
         while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
         return route;
       }),
       filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
       mergeMap((route) => route.data)
      )
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this._seoService.updateTitle(event['title']);
        this._seoService.updateOgUrl(event['ogUrl']);
        //Updating Description tag dynamically with title
        this._seoService.updateDescription(event['title'] + event['description'])
      }); 
    }
```

Then configure your routes like

```
      { 
        path: 'about', 
        component: AboutComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'About',
          description:'Description Meta Tag Content',
          ogUrl: 'your og url'
        } 
      },
```

IMHO this is a clear way of dealing with meta tags. You can update facebook and twitter specific tags easier.

Comment: I have everything in place, but "_seoService" is giving me issues in app.component. It's saying '[ts] Property 'seoService' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'." Which makes sense. How should I define "_seoService"?

Comment: Import SEOService in your app.module.ts providers section. then in your component where you set meta tags and titles, Inject SEOService in constructor like 
`constructor(public _seoService: SEOService)`

Comment: All hail Okan! Seems to work like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Also import the following:
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';`

Comment: In your data section, how do you handle ":"? For example, you have title: and description: without quotes. How do you handle og:url in the data section?

Comment: this is not complete solution for facebook or twitter tags. you can add a new method with content like `this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:url', content: urlcontent })`

Comment: I am trying to serve up different twitter card tags from different routes. This approach doesn't seem to work. However you stated, " You can update facebook and twitter specific tags easier." Can you point me to a reference, please?

Comment: Edited the answer, hope I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: @OkanAslankan It helps a lot, THANK YOU! How can I check whether it really works or not?

Comment: @HaifengZhang It should be working if the title changes. You can  check `<meta>` tags under `<head>` for other properties you want to set. (F11 on chrome)

Comment: Will router.events subscription invoke on page reload/refresh?

Comment: Yes, ideally in your root component: app.component.ts. You can implement a new service to handle it also.

Answer (score 21):

**Angular 6+ and RxJS 6+ solution for dynamically set title on route change**

If/when you upgrade to Angular 6 this is the solution there.

This service will:

- Update meta title on route change.
- Option to override title for any reasons you want that.

Create/change your SEO/meta service to the following.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MetaService {
    constructor(
        private titleService: Title,
        private meta: Meta,
        private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    updateMetaInfo(content, author, category) {
        this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: content });
        this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'author', content: author });
        this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: category });
    }

    updateTitle(title?: string) {
        if (!title) {
            this.router.events
                .pipe(
                    filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
                    map(() => this.activatedRoute),
                    map((route) => {
                        while (route.firstChild) { route = route.firstChild; }
                        return route;
                    }),
                    filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
                    mergeMap((route) => route.data)).subscribe((event) => {
                        this.titleService.setTitle(event['title'] + ' | Site name');
                    });
        } else {
            this.titleService.setTitle(title + ' | Site name');
        }
    }
}
```

Import your service and call it in the contructor.

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private meta: MetaService) {
    this.meta.updateTitle();
}
```

And this still requires to format routes like this.

**Route file.ts**

```
{ 
    path: 'about', 
    component: AboutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'About',
      description:'Description Meta Tag Content'
    } 
  },
```

Hope this will help for you and other people looking to update the title/meta dynamically in Angular 6.

Comment: Where are you calling updateMetaInfo() function? should be in app.component.ts as this.meta.updateTitle();?

Answer (score 13):

[`Title`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title) and [`Meta`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta) are providers that were introduced in Angular 4 and supposed to do this on both server and client side.

To create or update `title` tag and `description` meta tag, it is:

```
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

constructor(public meta: Meta, public title: Title, ...) { ... }

...

this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: description }); 
this.title.setTitle(title);
```

Comment: I will try this, if this works then this is the answer

Comment: I've been looking for a quick, easy, and correct way for updating title tags and metadata, and this is it!  Thanks so much for providing this.  If I could mark it as the answer, I totally would.  If I could make one slight correction, though, those "this.meta..." items need to go inside the constructor brackets { }.  That's how it worked for me.


constructor(public title: Title, public meta: Meta) { 
    this.title.setTitle('This is my page title');
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'This is my description'});
}

Comment: @michaelt Glad it worked for you. `...` meant that `this.meta` is used somewhere inside the same class. It could be `ngOnInit` method or else.

Comment: @EstusFlask does this get crawled by search engines?

Comment: @pravindot17 Yes, if you use Angular SSR. If you don't use it, your question is basically whether setting `document.title`, etc dynamically is friendly to search engines, and the answer is that it's more or less friendly to Google only.

Answer (score 4):

Since Angular pages are rendered at client side, its not possible for crawlers to detect meta tags. Most of the crawlers do not execute javascript at runtime due to which dynamic meta tags are not detected. This is true even for Facebook and Twitter.

Its required to use **Angular Universal for Server Side Rendering** or prerendering service e.g **prerender.io**

Edit:- I cam across a good youtube tutorial for this. Below is the link,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lncsmB5yfzE

Comment: Google is now rendering the page and most of the other search engines do.

Comment: Facebook still does not. If you test in Facebook developer tools you will come to know it still does not pick up the tags.

Answer (score 2):

IMO using data (title, description etc) in the Routes array is not so consistent, we can aggregate all the data in one place. Also in 2021, we can use common Angular tools out of the box:

seo-sitemap.ts

```
export const seoSitemap: ISitemapTag[] = [
  { customUrl: '/contact', title: null, description: 'Some description there', image: '/assets/path/to/image' },
{ customUrl: '/about', title: 'custom about title', description: 'Some description about', image: '/assets/path/to/another-image' }
];

export interface ISitemapTag {
  customUrl: string;
  title: string | null;
  description: string | null;
  image: string | null;
}
```

metatags.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta, MetaDefinition, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class MetatagsService {
  constructor(private title: Title, private meta: Meta) {}

  updateTitle(title: string) {
    this.title.setTitle(title);
  }

  updateTag(tag: MetaDefinition) {
    this.meta.updateTag(tag);
  }

  updateTags(tags: Array<MetaDefinition | null>) {
    tags.forEach((tag) => {
      tag && this.meta.updateTag(tag);
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { MetatagsService } from './shared/services/metatags.service';
import { seoSitemap } from './seoSitemap';

constructor() {
    this.sub = this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.setMetaTags(event);
      }
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() { this.sub && this.sub.unsubscribe() }

private setMetaTags(event: NavigationEnd) {
      const item = seoSitemap.find((i) => event.urlAfterRedirects === i.customUrl);
      if (item) {
        if (item.title) this.metatagsService.updateTitle(item.title);

        this.metatagsService.updateTags([
          item.description ? { name: 'description', content: item.description } : null,
          item.image ? { name: 'image', content: item.image } : null,
        ]);
        this.metatagsService.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: window.location.href });
      } else {
        this.metatagsService.updateTitle('Common title there');
      }
  }
```

Comment: that is a elegant solution

Answer (score -1):

**Here are the relevant parts from my project. (Angular 2/4)**

---

**app-routing.module.ts:**

> **Routes:**

```
... const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'path1', loadChildren: './path1#path1Module',
        data: {
            title: '...',
            description: '...',
            keywords: '...'
        }
    },
    {
        path: 'path2', loadChildren: './path2#path2Module',
        data: {
            title: '...',
            description: '...',
            keywords: '...'
        }
    } ...
```

**app.component.ts (or your bootstrap component):**

> imports:

```
// imports
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import { Title,Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

> constructor:

```
    // constructor:
        constructor(private router: Router,
                    private route: ActivatedRoute,
                    private titleService: Title, private meta: Meta) {}
```

> **ngOnInit() method:**

```
ngOnInit() {

        this.router.events
            .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .map(() => this.route)
            .map((route) => {
                while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
                return route;
            })
            .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
            .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
            .subscribe((event) => {
                this.updateDescription(event['description'], event['keywords'], event['title']);
            });

    }
```

> **method that updates title and meta tags -> called from ngOnInit():**

```
updateDescription(desc: string, keywords: string, title: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle(title);
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: desc })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: keywords })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:title', content: title })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:description', content: desc })
}
```

**Hope it helps.**