# Add meta description based on current page in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-seo

Hi I'm using Angular 13 to build a small  website. The project contains 5 components and each component have their own meta-tags and descriptions. When I am switching from one component to another and try to "view the source code"  I want to see the meta-tag and description of that component, but its showing only the meta-type and description of Index.html file.

below is my sample code for the child component for which I want to see the meta title and meta description but it is not working. Can any one please suggest a solution.

### index.html

```
<head> 
    <title> Title here  </title> 
    <meta data-rh="true" name="description" content=" Description is here"/> 
</head>
```

### Typescript file for child component

```
export class NoticeComponent implements OnInit { 
    ngOnInit() {
        this.meta.updateTag({name:'keywords',content:'Title-1 here'}); 
        this.meta.updateTag({name:'description',content:'Description-1 is here '}); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330535/dynamically-add-meta-description-based-on-route-in-angular

Comment: I will try this type but in my case this solutions is not work.

Comment: Please post the entire code snippet where you are facing this issue. Specially the constructor function.