# Why the meta tag is not getting added in view source code while it is seen during inspect element in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am using a service to fetch meta tags from an external server. I am getting the meta tag and visible while inspecting the element but it is not seen in the view source code.

```
mycomponent.ts
-------------
public commonmeta: any;
constructor(private blogservice: FetchBlogService, private metaservice: Meta) {
    
}

showAllBlogs(){
    this.blogservice.getHomeBlogs().
    subscribe(data => {
        this.commonmeta=data.commonmeta;
        this.metaservice.addTag({name: 'description', content: this.commonmeta.description});
      }
    );
  }
ngAfterViewInit() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showAllBlogs();
      }, 0);
  }

app.module.ts
--------------
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
providers: [Meta ],
})
```

Comment: Can you please share working example of your problem for better understanding?

Comment: You mean the website link?

Comment: I am getting the meta tag using the above code while inspecting elements but the meta tag is not visible when viewing via view source code.

Comment: Are you using changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush ? 
Not your website link exactly, you can share your problem code part on https://stackblitz.com/ and share link to understand.

Comment: No I am not using any changeDetection. The above code is the only thing which I have used .  I can see the meta tag been added when inspecting element, but that is not visible when viewing via view source code. The above code is working well with no error.

Comment: I have added the code link: https://angular-ivy-gqyfrn.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Sorry, but not able to access this link, getting white screen only.

Comment: I am not getting any proper solution from anyone. Please anyone can help?

Comment: Please check this link already answered related to meta tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330535/dynamically-add-meta-description-based-on-route-in-angular
This may help.