how to add meta tags for SEO on each page or URL in angular?
I notice some online shopping website and other website have meta tags for every items that I google. And the meta tags change for every page or url I visit in the web site.
How do I do that in angular? Do I have to add every keyword in the meta tags or can I generate them?
I am still new in angular and I only know that there is only 1 head in an angular app.

A similar question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330535/dynamically-add-meta-description-based-on-route-in-angular
You can also read more here: https://angular.dev/api/platform-browser/Meta
